# Does vscode for c++ listen to clangs format file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have following settings in vscode:

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "Visual Studio",
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Visual Studio",
"editor.formatOnType": true
```

Which should make new lines before braces almost everywhere (BreakBeforeBraces: Allman), but it does nowhere:

```
int main(){
 std::cout << "abcd";
}
```

there is does not break, despite the settings. What I want:

```
int main()
{
 std::cout << "abcd";
}
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: @ThomasSablik did not know it is needed, I will. However despite not having it yet, having setting on "Visual Code" should already be sufficient to provide formatting or?

Comment: Have you installed clang format on your system?

Comment: @ThomasSablik installed, now I see no .clang-format to edit. Only the executable `/usr/lib/llvm-7/bin/clang-format`, what else?

Comment: `If no .clang-format file is found in your workspace, formatting is applied based on a default style specified in the C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle setting instead. ` from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide says it should apply the formating regardless the `.clang-format`, so you were wrong. So why (having fall-back format set to Visual Code) does not work alone?

Comment: Is `clang-format` in your PATH?

Comment: env | grep clang` == nothing

Comment: formatOnType doesn't work for me. Try formatOnSave.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes, but this is not the solved problem, I wanted the behaviour, that is in visual code -> after braces, when pressed new line, the brace is also put on new line, while typing. I can make the formatting OnSave, but that is not full solution

Comment: _"after braces, when pressed new line, the brace is also put on new line, while typing."_ So it works for you on type?

Comment: @ThomasSablik no, it does not. It is the desired behaviour, but only works in visual code. Cannot find a way to make it work in vscode with c/c++ windows extension

Comment: What's the difference between _"visual code"_ and _"vscode with c/c++ windows extension"_? Why haven't you described it in your question? I assume _"vscode"_ and _"visual code"_ are both short forms of visual studio code.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am sorry, I meant visual studio (not code). The c# IDE in windows. There is the newline-newbrace behaviour. Not in the vscode(editor, not IDE) with c/c++ extension (where I am trying to achieve this)

Comment: I think it's a known bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94198